# Xamarin Studio can't open solution after update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

After update Xamarin Studio to version 6.2 (Cycle9), I can't open any solution. Xamarin Studio starts fine, but when I try to open any project, it crash and end program asking me if want to report error to Apple.

- I tryed to change the update Chanel but all contains the same versions.
- Also I reinstalled Xamarin (uninstall Xamarin, restart Pc, install Xamarin), but still giving the same error.

Did someone know what should i do? I can add the error trace if needed.

There are a [forum thread for this release in bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/buglist.cgi?f1=creation_ts&f2=cf_tags&f3=resolution&f4=resolution&n3=1&o1=greaterthan&o2=anywordssubstr&o3=anyexact&query_format=advanced&v1=2017-02-22%2021%3A00&v2=Cycle9I%20Cycle9R&v3=DUPLICATE%2CINVALID) where this [issue is already reported](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52695), but there is no answer.

Comment: I think I am looking for how to downgrade to preview version.

Comment: I would open a bug on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with the information from the About dialog - Show details and the IDE log with the crash information - Help - Open Log Directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time waiting for that error to be fixed. Finally a new version of Xamarin Studio was released (6.2.1). I installed it thoughting that the error has been fixed, but it was not like that. So I immersed myself in the search of the solution and found [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89393/xamarin-studio-for-mac-crashes-after-latest-update).

- **SOLUTION:**

Disable the Subversion Add-in:

1. Go to the Xamarin Studio menu.
2. Select Add-ins.
3. Search for Subversion
4. Click the Disable button.

Comment: This fixed the error completely. I could open/create project in Xamarin Studio >= 6.2.0 releases.

I hop they fix it soon because I use Subversion for my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade Xamarin Studio to 6.1.5 like explained [here](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1699777-how-do-i-downgrade-to-an-older-version-). Makes solutions ables to be opened / created again.

Be sure you choose the Xamarin Studio "select" for you operating system and not another component.

Comment: This is not the valid answer, because don't explain how to resolve the issue. But I can continue with my work while this is solved.